# Text-overflow:ellipsis and Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ellipsis

I want to have a box with text and an Icon inside. The Icon is supposed to stick to the right side of the box, the text to the left.
If the text is too long to fit into the box next to the icon, I want it to be shortend by the `text-overflow:ellipsis` property. I do not insist on implementing it with Flex-Box, if there is a better way to do it.

It should look like this:

[image]

And this is what I achieved so far:

```css
div#Wrapper {
  border: 0.2em solid black;
  width: 6em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: flex;
}


span#Text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


span#Icon {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
Short Text:
<div id="Wrapper">
  <span id="Text">
    This
  </span>
  <span id="Icon"> 
  </span>
</div>

<br><br><br>

Text:
<div id="Wrapper">
  <span id="Text">
    This is Text
  </span>
  <span id="Icon"> 
  </span>
</div>

<br><br><br>

Long Text:
<div id="Wrapper">
  <span id="Text">
    This is long long long Text
  </span>
  <span id="Icon"> 
 
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Id's should be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `flex: 1` and `overflow: hidden` properties on `text` element.

```css
div#Wrapper {
  border: 0.2em solid black;
  width: 6em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: flex;
}
span#Text {
  flex: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
span#Icon {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="Wrapper">
  <span id="Text">
    This is long long long Text
  </span>
  <span id="Icon"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the ID's with classes since the ID must be unique in the document. Furthermore, I added [overflow: hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) for the text and `flex: 0 0 auto` for the icon.

```css
div#Wrapper {
  border: 0.2em solid black;
  width: 6em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: flex;
}

span.Text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden; /* Added */
}

span.Icon {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto; /* Added */
}
```

```html
Short Text:
<div id="Wrapper">
  <span class="Text">
    This
  </span>
  <span class="Icon"> 
  </span>
</div>

<br><br><br> Text:
<div id="Wrapper">
  <span class="Text">
    This is Text
  </span>
  <span class="Icon"> 
  </span>
</div>

<br><br><br> Long Text:
<div id="Wrapper">
  <span class="Text">
    This is long long long Text
  </span>
  <span class="Icon"> 
 
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

https://jsfiddle.net/hxz05g9j

Another approach is make circle as `:after` css.